# Best way to store points of a curve created by touch movements?

Tags: android, bezier

We are creating an app where it is necessary to draw lines (curves) based on touch events but we also need to store the points that correspond to specific lines.

Android.Graphics.Path gave us really nice smooth lines as we dragged our finger. However, there does not seem to be anyway to access the points from the Path objects.

What we do now is basically connect lines as a person drags their finger (using y=mx+b). So if the last recognized touch place was 0,0 and then they move past our threshold to (4,4) we call a function to make points from the line connecting these two ((0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)). These points we add to an ArrayList.

This is giving us kinda choppy curves (obviously cause we are using y=mx+b), but more importantly it slows our program considerably after several lines are drawn.

Is there a better way to generate the points of a curve that follows a user's swipe movements? Or a better way to store these? Path seems to do it so well, is there any reason it hides the actual points?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve smoothness is using the Path class' method quadTo.

> quadTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) Add a quadratic bezier
>   from the last point, approaching control point (x1,y1), and ending at
>   (x2,y2).

Comment: Yes but we cant store these points. It draws very smooth lines but we need access to all the points that are being drawn

Answer (score 0):

Bezier curves are what you want to solve this problem. You should be able to detect a change in direction of the user's finger and stop the current curve and start a new one at that point. You really don't want to be storing every point along a path as I could just let my finger linger on the screen and clog up the datastructure.